# Uploaded files not publicly readable with ACL set

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am currently working on an app running on GAE which will accept an image upload and then write it to could storage with the GCS Client library (previously used the Cloud Storage API with the same results).  The issue I am seeing is that after it is written, the files are accessible only if you are already logged in with a Google account.  I have billing enabled and my GAE id (XXXXXX@appspot.gserviceaccount.com) is added as a team member into the Google API project as an owner

I have used the command: `gsutil setdefacl public-read gs://mybucket`  (Bucket name is correct in live code).

I have the following entry in my ACL:

```
<Entry>
  <Scope type="AllUsers"/>
    <Permission>
      READ
  </Permission>
</Entry>
```

And I am initializing the write with this code:

```
GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService();
GcsFilename filename = new GcsFilename(bucket, fileName);
GcsFileOptions options = new GcsFileOptions.Builder()
  .mimeType(mime)
  .acl("public-read").build();
GcsOutputChannel writeChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(filename, options);
```

The app returns the url of the file to the client, which as I mentioned works fine for any Google user, but any other user is redirected when they attempt to access the https://storage.cloud.google.com/mybucket/filename.png url.  Also,  when I am logged into the cloud storage web interface, when I mousover the box in the "SHARED PUBLICLY" column (which has a dash in it)  I receive a hover message "You do not have permission to view or edit this object's ACL's".  I can however delete the file with no problem, and the account I'm logged in with is set as an owner of the API project.

I'm sure I'm missing something easy here, but I've been over all the docs and have been working on this for a couple days.  Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Could you post the resulting acls of one of the files. Note also that you could upload a file directly to Cloud Storage through GAE. See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/UploadOptions.Builder.html#withGoogleStorageBucketName(java.lang.String).

Comment: When I attempt to check the ACL through gsutil, I get this:
    
`$ ./gsutil getacl  gs://mybucket/e7b2b0f2-d378-11e2-aa17-60b97f511988.png

GSResponseError: status=403, code=AccessDenied, reason=Forbidden, detail=tclvpics/e7b2b0f2-d378-11e2-aa17-60b97f511988.png.`

This seems strange as I am the owner of this API project, I even reran gsutil config to double check that I was acting as the correct user

Comment: i need help for similar task, could you plz check into 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17427931/not-able-to-upload-files-from-gae-project-to-google-cloud-storage-using-gcs-clie

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Public Read Issue

The `storage.cloud.google.com` domain is used by the Cloud Storage UI, which is only accessible as a logged-in user. It is not the API endpoint. You should use `https://storage.googleapis.com/bucketname/objectname` or `https://bucketname.storage.googleapis.com/objectname`.

### Permission Denied for Editing ACL

Only a user with `FULL_CONTROL` on an object or the owner of an object can view the object's ACL. It sounds like the object is owned by your service account, and your account doesn't have `FULL_CONTROL` on the object, so it can't view the ACL. You can still delete the object because a user with `FULL_CONTROL` on a bucket always has the ability to delete objects in the bucket.

Comment: Wow,  I can't believe I missed that.  Thanks so much, that was it.

Comment: But according to GCS doc, "The project owners and project writers group have FULL_CONTROL permission on the object." So the user "the account I'm logged in with is set as an owner of the API project." should have access to the ACL. right?

Comment: Only if the ACL is some subset of project-private. For example, if user A uploads an object with predefined ACL "private", then user B, who is an owner of the BUCKET, will be able to delete the object but will not be able to view the object or the object's ACL.

Answer (score 0):

Related note: I think you can reduce CPU cost by using blobstore API directly to upload image to GCS. 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#using-blobstore-with-gcs