# Not able to upload files from GAE project to Google cloud Storage using GCS Client library+java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload image/file to google cloud storage from my GAE application using new Gcs Client Library.

Here is the code snippet

```
GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService(new RetryParams.Builder()
          .initialRetryDelayMillis(10)
          .retryMaxAttempts(10)
          .totalRetryPeriodMillis(15000)
          .build());
GcsFilename filename = new GcsFilename(BUCKETNAME, FILENAME);
GcsFileOptions options = new GcsFileOptions.Builder().mimeType("text/html").acl("public-read").build();
GcsOutputChannel writeChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(filename,options);           
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(Channels.newWriter(writeChannel, "UTF8"));
out.println("The woods are lovely dark and deep.");
out.println("But I have promises to keep.");
out.flush();
writeChannel.waitForOutstandingWrites();
writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap("And miles to go before I sleep.".getBytes()));
writeChannel.close();
```

When i look into the logs i am getting 403 error like this

```
Server replied with 403, check that ACLs are set correctly on the object and bucket:
Request: POST https://storage.googleapis.com/<bucket name>/<object name>
x-goog-resumable: start
x-goog-api-version: 2
Content-Type: text/html
x-goog-acl: public-read

no content

Response: 403 with 152 bytes of content
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 152
Date: Tue, 02 Jul 2013 14:10:02 GMT
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Jun 28 2013 13:27:54 (1372451274)
X-Google-Cache-Control: remote-fetch
Via: HTTP/1.1 GWA
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access denied.</Message><Details>images2.solestruck.com</Details></Error>
```

Can someone help me in fixing this.

Comment: Have you added your app engine service account to BUCKETNAME's permissions? See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/#Prerequisites for instructions on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks alot, it really helped me to fix this issue.

Comment: I have one more small issue. Now, i could able to upload images successfully, when i look into the cloud storage using Store manager, i could see the "Share Publicly" is not checked. I am setting acl as "public-read". Could you plz help me in this.

Comment: Is it possible you've set the bucket acl and not the object acl? What does the manager show the full acl as being?

Comment: I am trying to set acl only through this statement 

    "GcsFileOptions options = new GcsFileOptions.Builder().mimeType("text/html").acl("public-read").build();"

how to set acl for the objects.

Comment: Hi, i have a question. So far we are using JetS3t to upload images to google cloud storage, is google still going to support this, as Google Storage API is deprecated. Is there any relation between Google Storage API & JetS3t & Gcs Client Library. Please advice

Comment: App engine provides its own special interfaces to Google Cloud Storage, which provide benefits to app engine developers. The Files API method is deprecated in favor of the cloud storage api for app engine. However, I believe (but could be wrong) that JetS3t accesses Google Cloud Storage via the standard Google Cloud Storage API and not the appengine-specific one, so I would imagine you'd be fine.

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem. Follow instructions below (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/#Java_Prerequisites)

> Give permissions to your bucket or objects. To enable your app to
>   create new objects in a bucket, you need to do the following:
>
> Log into the App Engine Admin Console. Click on the application you
>   want to authorize for your Cloud Storage bucket. Click on Application
>   Settings under the Administration section on the left-hand side. Copy
>   the value under Service Account Name. This is the service account name
>   of your application, in the format
>   application-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com. If you are using an App
>   Engine Premier Account, the service account name for your application
>   is in the format
>   application-id.example.com@appspot.gserviceaccount.com.
>
> Grant access permissions using the following methods: The easiest way
>   to grant app access to a bucket is to use the Google APIs Console to
>   add the service account name of the app as a team member to the
>   project that contains the bucket.(The app should have edit permissions
>   if it needs to write to the bucket.) For information about permissions
>   in Cloud Storage, see Scopes and Permissions. Add more apps to the
>   project team if desired.

It works for me.